# GTM - Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: google-tag-manager

When I added the installation code of GTM to my site, I encounter error "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined". I am not really sure where is the problem on my end.

[image]

When I tried removing this specific code of gtm ,

```
f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
```

the error's gone. Did you encounter same problem or have an idea to the possible cause? Please help. Thank You

Comment: Removing "f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);" removes GTM from your page. This removes any JS within GTM, so you do not get an error anymore. Apparently some tag  in GTM uses jquery and tries to access a DOM element that does not exist.

Comment: Is GTM website specific? the gtm codes is just only given to me so I'm not sure about the setup. And its working on our main website, no errors. The one with errors are like clone of the main website, files and codes are basically the same. That's why I am not sure where's the problem.